# Unable to list all files in $HOME directory

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

I installed the latest version of `cygwin` and wanted to list all files in my `$HOME` direcrory (in paticular `.vimrc` config file). I type `ls -l` and see 0 files, but when I try to open the file via vim it's ok. Actually (after 2 `TAB`s):

[image]

what's wrong?

Comment: `ls` doesn't list dot-files (files that start with a `.`) by default. Try `ls -A` or `ls -a`.

Answer (score 5):

In *nix systems, prefixing a name with `.` causes the item to be hidden.

To include these files when you type `ls -l`, you will need to include the `-a` modifier.

You can write this as `ls -la` for brevity, if you like.

In the future, if you're having trouble with a program, you can type (e.g.) `man ls` to open the *man*ual pages for (e.g.) `ls`.

Comment: Beginning a file name with `.` does indeed "hide" it from _default_ listing via `ls`, but that's about it.  It's not "hidden" for most other purposes.